# Const error for this or no viable overload `=`

Tags: c++, templates, constants

I guess this is caused by my overloads of `=` operator. But I don't know why, even after I simplify the code for 9 times.

test9.cpp:

```
template<typename T>
class A {
public:
    A(const T x): _x(x) {}
    A() : _x(0) {}

    template<typename T2>
    void operator=(const A<T2> &rhs) {
        _x = rhs._x;
    }
    T _x;
};

template <typename T>
class A_wrap {
public:
    A_wrap(const T x) : _a(x) {}
    const A<T> _a;
};

template <typename T>
class X {
public:
    X() {}
    const int test() const {
        const A_wrap<T> a_wrap(10);
        _a = a_wrap._a;
    }
    A<T> _a;
};

int main() {
    // This works.
    A<int> _a;
    const A_wrap<int> a_wrap(10);
    _a = a_wrap._a;
    // Below doesn't compile.
    X<int> x;
    x.test(); 
}
```

Error: g++ 6

```
test9.cpp:39:12:   required from here
test9.cpp:27:12: error: passing ‘const A<int>’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
         _a = a_wrap._a;
         ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
test9.cpp:2:7: note:   in call to ‘constexpr A<int>& A<int>::operator=(const A<int>&)’
 class A {
       ^
```

Error clang++ 3.8.1:

```
test9.cpp:27:12: error: no viable overloaded '='
        _a = a_wrap._a;
        ~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~
test9.cpp:39:7: note: in instantiation of member function 'X<int>::test' requested here
    x.test(); 
      ^
test9.cpp:2:7: note: candidate function (the implicit copy assignment operator) not viable: 'this'
      argument has type 'const A<int>', but method is not marked const
class A {
      ^
test9.cpp:8:10: note: candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const A<int>', but
      method is not marked const
    void operator=(const A<T2> &rhs) {
         ^
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `test()` member function of `X`

```
const int test() const {
    const A_wrap<T> a_wrap(10);
    _a = a_wrap._a;
}
```

is defined to be `const`, i.e., not to change the state of the class. However, you are changing the value of the member variable `_a`, hence the error. You need to remove the last `const` in function:

```
const int test() {
    const A_wrap<T> a_wrap(10);
    _a = a_wrap._a;
}
```

Also the `const` in the return value of type int doesn't do much as it can be copied to a non-constant `int`. Returning a reference is an other matter though.

Comment: thanks a lot. have been on this "thing" for like 2 hrs